# Is this a dictionary & lists bug?

Tags: python, list, debugging, append

Can anybody make sense of this:

Method 1

```
In[25]: dico = {'A': [], 'B': []}
In[26]: dico['A'].append(1)
In[27]: print(dico)
{'B': [], 'A': [1]}
```

Method 2

```
In[28]: letters = ['A', 'B']
In[29]: dico = dict.fromkeys(letters, [])
In[30]: print(dico)
{'B': [], 'A': []}
In[31]: dico['A'].append(1)
In[32]: print(dico)
{'B': [1], 'A': [1]}
```

I cannot figure out why in the 2nd case the value is appended in each key.... this is a serious bug or I am seriously tired.....

Comment: Because `dict.fromkeys` will *not* create copies of the fillvalue implicitly, and the *same list object* is used as the value for every key. This is usually how things in Python work. Certainly, all built-in functions/methods will work like this.

Comment: You're not using pandas at all here.

Comment: OK, thanks for your response. Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Yes sorry, I use it just after in my script... I am building a dataframe from a dictionary, the issue I have is to populate the lists included in the dictionary....

Comment: OK I found a solution, simply: dico['A'] = dico['A'] + ['1'].

Comment: `fromkeys` is a trap. Use a dict comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this nicely with a dictionary comprehension:

```
dico = {k: [] for k in letters}
```